# NoMethodError: undefined method `unresolved_deps' for Gem:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm running rails 3.2.13 on ruby-1.9.3-p429 on RVM and I'm suddenly getting an error in irb that I'd like some help with. When I execute a method on a object, I get the error 'NoMethodError: undefined method `unresolved_deps' for Gem:Module' which comes from /Users/sirbertly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in`require'. I've done some research and I think this is due to conflicting rubygems, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any ideas would be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `rvm info rvm`, `gem env`, `which ruby`, `echo $GEM_PATH` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: I have same issue. How did you solve that problem? I got this error after executed `gem update --system` command as recommended on rubygems.org's page.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.  I finally tracked it down to the fact that I had upgraded rubygems to 2.x.  And it states in the release notes for 2.0.0:

Breaking changes:

- Deprecated Gem.unresolved_deps in favor of
  Gem::Specification.unresolved_deps

Since I use rvm, I went back to the latest 1.8.x version

`rvm rubygems 1.8.26`

There may be other/better ways to fix it, but this did it for me.  I thought re-installing ruy 1.9.3 would fix it, but it seems to be tied to the 1.8.x version of rubygems.